# How to access metrics which is located in another namespace in prometheus in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Suppose there is an Application which is located in namespace called "API" and the Prometheus Server which is located in namespace "prometheus", how can I access my Application from Prometheus Server if both of the Server and Application are in different namespaces?

I've tried to specify following construction `<application-service-name>.API.svc.cluster.local:<application-service-port>` as a reference to the Application, but it does not seems to work

And the Prometheus responds in the UI with `Connection Refused`.

```yaml
scrape_configs: 
   
   - job_name: 'some-job' 

       kubernetes_sd_configs:
          namespaces: 
             names: 'API'

       scrape_interval: 10s   
       scrape_timeout: 5s 

       static_configs:
          - targets: ['application-service-name>.API.svc.cluster.local:<application-service-port>']
```

Comment: Prometheus metrics are served in a basic plain-text format over HTTP, so the normal `service.namespace.svc.cluster.local` DNS name should work.  Can you make a `curl` request to that hostname and port from a different pod?

Comment: Well, What I've tried is 1. Connect to the Prometheus  Server via kubectl `kubectl exec -it <pod_name> -- /bin/sh`     2. `ping <service>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port>` but the response is `ping: bad address 'payment-service.payment-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8000'`, despite the fact that it's running.....

Comment: Okay, have to edit my response a bit, there was the wrong name of the service, so the final url would be `payment-internal-service.payment-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8000` and it pings fine from the Prometheus rn, but when I go to the Prometheus UI, for some reasons it still cannot find it, `*I've changed the config of prometheus and set up updated urls,  but it does not seems to react on it anyway`

Comment: You should be able to do something like `curl http://payment-service.payment-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8000/metrics` and see a plain-text dump of the metrics.

Comment: Yeah, It works totally okay on localhost and in the prometheus pod itself, but when I connect to my prometheus-server and go to the UI, it shows: `Get "http://payment-internal-service.payment-namespace.svc.cluster.local:8000/metrics": dial tcp 10.101.156.194:8000: connect: connection refused`